# "None of the supported PHP extensions are available" error while upgrading PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Since I upgraded from 5.0 version to 5.5 I am getting the following error on my PHP page.

> None of the supported PHP extensions (MySQLi, MySQL, PDO_MySQL) are available.

---

When I tried to install `php-mysql` package, I got the following error.

```
# yum install php-mysql --skip-broken

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_4.2.x86_64 from base
    php-mysql-5.1.6-27.el5.x86_64 from base
```

This was working as expected when I had 5.0 version of MySQL. How do I upgrade the php extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing mysql shared compact library, this was working as expected

```
wget ftp://ftp.isu.edu.tw/pub/Unix/Database/MySQL/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.24-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ihv MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.24-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
yum install php-mysql --skip-broken
```